# Is there are tool for recursively converting 64-bit filenames to 32-bit filenames?

Tags: filesystem, filename, format-conversion

I have a flash drive that I want to put a bunch of files on, but they have 64-bit filenames (they're on an EXT4 filesystem currently), and the flash drive needs to be FAT32, which doesn't accept some characters or filename lenghts. Is there a tool that will automatically convert conflicting filenames into something functional for FAT32?

I'm using Xubuntu 16.10 64-bit.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're looking for is just the rename utility...

For instance this would rename every file longer than 10 character to the first 10 characters:

```
rename 's/^(.{10}).*/$1/' *
```

so "superlongfilename" becomes "superlongf" but you run the risk of files overwriting each other if they truncate to the same name. You can to a "trial run" without making any real changes with the "-n" switch, which will just print what it would do.

The rename utility supports regex (obviously) so you can match/replace/substitute as needed to meet your needs...